# Compiling a function while dealing with symmetries

Tags: function-construction, compile

I have the following function that I would like to compile:

```
 r12ExpUnit[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] := 

      r12ExpUnit[n3, n4, n1, n2] = 

        r12ExpUnit[n1, n4, n3, n2] = 

            r12ExpUnit[n3, n2, n1, n4] =

 mx[n1, n2, n3, n4]*Sum[((-1)^(m1 + m2 + m3 + m4)*bc[n1 + 1, m1 + 2]*bc[n2 + 1, m2 + 2]*bc[n3 + 1, m3 + 2]*bc[n4 + 1, m4 + 2]*bc[m1 + m3, m1]*bc[m2 + m4, m2])*
 ((sq1[m2, m4]/sq2[m1, m3])*(s1[m1, m2, m3, m4] + s2[m1, m2, m3, m4]*(m2 + m4 + 3)*(m2 + m4 + 2)) + (sq1[m1, m3]/sq2[m2, m4])*(s3[m1, m2, m3, m4] + s4[m1, m2, m3, m4]*(m1 + m3 + 3)*(m1 + m3 + 2))), {m1, 0, n1 - 1}, 
{m2, 0, n2 - 1}, {m3, 0, n3 - 1}, {m4, 0, n4 - 1}];
```

I would like to declare `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, `n4` as integers as they are merely indices; however, I am not sure how to do so while still maintaining that

```
r12ExpUnit[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] :=  r12ExpUnit[n3, n4, n1, n2] =  r12ExpUnit[n1, n4, n3, n2] = r12ExpUnit[n3, n2, n1, n4]
```

Any suggestions on how to compile this code would be much appreciated, as well as any other suggestions to significantly speed up this calculation.  Thanks!

Comment: `SetAttributes[r12ExpUnit, Orderless]` should help. Compiling, not so much.

Comment: To clarify, by "compile" do you mean construct/code a function or [`Compile[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) it?

Comment: I was referring to Compile[]

Comment: You can arrange things so that your compiled function takes four arguments like usual, and have a front-end function that has the `Orderless` attribute.

Comment: The input is not orderless however.  n1 and n3 are interchangeable, and n2 and n4 are interchangeable.  Is there a way to deal with only the pairs being orderless?